# how to open file.html and use fwrite using submit button?

Tags: php, html, button, submit

basically i want to generate a thank you page, every time the user hits submit button after writing their emails (which i will aquire through fwrite ), a new html page is generated and thank you is written on it. i have done the list part:

```
 <?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
  $email =$_POST['email'];
  $file = fopen("list.txt","a+") or die("file not open");

  $s= $email;
  fputs($file,$s."  ") or die("data not written");
  fclose($file);
    }
   ?>
```

Comment: Is all file permissions are correct?

Comment: yes all file permissions are correct

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What happens if two users submit the form at the exact same time?

Comment: their email gets written on my list file and a new page saying thank you or a site (eg:google.com) opens.

Comment: This could really be a single page that where you show the form if there is not POST and a thank you message if there is a POST and everything validates okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new page name it something like `thank_you.php` and right after  `fclose($file);` redirect to to thank you page.

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
    $email =$_POST['email'];
    $file = fopen("list.txt","a+") or die("file not open");

    $s= $email;
    fputs($file,$s."  ") or die("data not written");
    fclose($file);
    header("Location: thank_you.php");
  }
```

?>

Comment: thank_you.php is opening but its blank, though  I have written code on it

Comment: <?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
           
            echo "<html><head><title>Thanks!</title></head>
                    <body>
                        <p>nthankss</p>
                    </body>
                  </html>" ;

            }
            ?>

Comment: isset($_POST['submit'] don't work after redirection you can just add plain html in thank_you page. Or you can send GET parameter while redirecting and check with isset() on thank_you page.

Comment: and if I want to open a google.com when user hits submit what should I do?

Comment: just redirect to google.com like header("Location: http://google.com");

Comment: this poped up :The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error. 
If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Answer (score 0):

After you're done with the logic of your script, echo some HTML to display a web page in the browser. So, after you `fclose($file); }`, add this:

```
echo "<html><head><title>Thanks!</title></head>
        <body>
            <p>Thank you.</p>
        </body>
      </html>" ;
```

Comment: <p> Thank you </p> gets printed on the top of my webpage. I want it on a new page.

Comment: It would be helpful to have more information about everything on this page, then, including information about how this PHP is being called. For example, my answer, or an answer suggesting `header('Location:...')` won't work if you've already printed content to the screen, but there's no way for us to know that you've already printed content to the screen from the code you've provided. Can you show us the whole script/page?

Comment: how to give you the whole script as my limit in comment box is exceeding.

Comment: Check out the guidance here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/html/info

"Questions regarding html and/or html5 should include a minimal Stack Snippet, a JSFiddle, Codepen or a JSBin demo of relevant code if requesting debugging help."

Answer (score 0):

Why you are generating new pages just only for Thank You. I will suggest you to create a new page ("/thanks.php") in which you can pass email dynamically like this.

```
            <?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
            $email =$_POST['email'];
            echo "<html><head><title>Thanks!</title></head>
                    <body>
                        <p>$email</p>
                    </body>
                  </html>" ;

            }
```

Comment: because I was also thinking to open a google.com also when user hits submit